# SQL Server stored procedure would required 0.1 sec to execute but Rest api would take 60 sec.Why?

Tags: sql-server, api, stored-procedures

This is my API query:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<VoucherReview>> Query(IDbConnection db)
{
    return await DapperExtensions.QueryAsync<VoucherReview>(db, "spDispatch_GetDBVoucherTrips", this, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout:60);
}
```

The `spDispatch_GetDBVoucherTrips` stored procedure would take 0.1 sec to execute. Why does the API take 60 seconds? Any suggestions?

Comment: it's almost certainly cached query plan: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html , I'm asssuming the fast execution is when you run from SSMS?

Comment: try to remove async and await then